# postgresql percentage comparison of different rows in a separate column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in POSTGRESQL that is actually a VIEW generated from a bunch of JOINS which eventually looks like this:

```
 test_type |  brand  | model  | band | firmware_version | avg_throughput
-----------+---------+--------+------+------------------+----------------
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 1.5              |          66.94
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 2.0              |          94.98
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 2.11             |         132.40
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 1.5              |         216.46
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 2.0              |         176.79
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 2.11             |         191.44
```

What I'd like to accomplish is creating another column which will compare and show a percentage difference of `throughput` between different `firmware versions` for each model.

More specifically the query will take the throughput of the lowest firmware version and save it as a base of comparison to the throughput for all the other firmware versions.

So if we take `Linksys N600`, the lowest firmware version is `1.5` and the throughput is `66.94` we will save that as a baseline and compare the other throughputs to that number and show the difference in percentage.

The final result of the table would look like this:

```
 test_type |  brand  | model  | band | firmware_version | avg_throughput | comparison
-----------+---------+--------+------+------------------+----------------+------------
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 1.5              |          66.94 | 0% (or empty)
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 2.0              |          94.98 | +41.61%
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 2.11             |         132.40 | +97.78%
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 0.5              |         216.46 | 0% (or empty)
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 1.2              |         176.79 | -18.32%
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 2.5              |         191.44 | -11.55%
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

I like to keep things logical and separated and for now am not considering doing this calculation in my code, I'd rather have this done on my database and then just show the result but am open to suggestion if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be solved using a window function:

```
select test_type, 
       brand, 
       model, 
       band, 
       firmware_version, 
       avg_throughput,
       ((avg_throughput / first_value(avg_throughput) over (partition by brand, model order by firmware_version)) - 1) * 100 as diff_to_first_version
from temp_table
order by model desc, firmware_version;
```

You can also add the difference to the previous version not just the first version by using `lag()` instead of `first_value()`

```
select test_type, 
       brand, 
       model, 
       band, 
       firmware_version, 
       avg_throughput,
       ((avg_throughput / first_value(avg_throughput) over (partition by brand, model order by firmware_version)) - 1) * 100 as diff_to_first_version,
       ((avg_throughput / lag(avg_throughput) over (partition by brand, model order by firmware_version)) - 1) * 100 as diff_to_prev_version
from temp_table
order by model desc, firmware_version;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9746f/1

This is going to be faster than the solution using a self-join on the table.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is by far the neatest query and thanks for the introduction to PARTITION.

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery on the view to return the base throughput from the earliest firmware versions for each model via a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html), then join your view to that:

```
select
  v.test_type, v.brand, v.model, v.band, v.firmware_version, v.avg_throughput,
  (100 * v.avg_throughput / b.avg_throughput)::decimal(8,2) - 100 as percent_gain
  from myview v
join (select test_type, brand, model, band,
      avg_throughput, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY test_type, brand, model, band
      order by firmware_version) as rank
      from myview) b
on v.test_type = b.test_type
and v.brand = b.brand
and v.model = b.model
and v.band = b.band
and rank = 1
```

[See SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ea079/10) using your sample data and producing your expected output.

You could do it using a correlated subquery instead of a join, but performance would be terrible, because such queries must be executed once for every *row*. By using a join like this, the query to fetch the minimums is executed just once.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very close to what I wanted to accomplish. Actually I need to get the throughput of the earliest (minimum) firmware version and then have the throughput of that as a baseline. I tried figuring this out myself but am not having luck yet.

Comment: what datatype is `firmware_version`? numeric or text? Asusming text, are they all of the form `n.nn`?, ie and not `n.n.nn`? The problem is that `2.11` is numerically "earlier" than `2.2`, but "Versionally" later (because `11` is greater than `2`). Figuring out which firmware version is "earlier" is actually a big part of the challenge. Let me know what formats they may be in

Comment: it's numeric, the versions I provided here are just an example, in reality the firmware versions are always consistent, so if I simply do min(firmware_version) that's enough for me to get the earliest version.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But `min(avg_throughput)` would select the lowest throughput, not the throughput of the first (lowest) firmware_version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK sorted (including a fiddle). At least i got to brush up on my window function syntax :) (and iphone thumbing Kung Fu)

Answer (score 0):

After some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270298/selecting-a-column-based-on-a-minimum-value-of-another-column/25270480) I came up with this query that does what I needed.

```
 SELECT
   v.test_type, v.brand, v.model, v.band, v.firmware_version, v.avg_throughput,
   ROUND((100 * v.avg_throughput / (CASE b.min_avg WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE b.min_avg END)) - 100::numeric, 2) AS percentage
FROM temp_table v
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (test_type, model) 
test_type, brand, model, band, firmware_version, avg_throughput AS min_avg
FROM temp_table
ORDER BY test_type, model, firmware_version) b
    ON v.test_type = b.test_type
    AND v.brand = b.brand
    AND v.model = b.model
    AND v.band = b.band;
```

Thanks everyone for all the help!