# selecting a column based on a minimum value of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table.

```
test_type |  brand  | model  | band | firmware_version | avg_throughput
-----------+---------+--------+------+-----------------+----------------
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 1               |          66.94
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 2               |          94.98
 1client   | Linksys | N600   | 5ghz | 4               |         132.40
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 1               |         216.46
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 2               |         176.79
 1client   | Linksys | EA6500 | 5ghz | 4               |         191.44
```

I'd like to select the `avg_throughput` of each `model` that has the lowest `firmware_version`.

When I do `SELECT test_type, model, min(firmware_version) FORM temp_table GROUP BY test_type, model` I get what I want but once I add the `avg_throughput` column it requires me to also add it to the GROUP BY clause which makes it return all the rows when all I need is only the `avg_throughput` for the lowest `firmware_version` for each `model` type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In standard SQL this can be done using a window function

```
select test_type, model, firmware_version, avg_throughput
from (
  select test_type, model, firmware_version, avg_throughput, 
         min(firmware_version) over (partition by test_type, model) as min_firmware
  from temp_table
) t
where firmware_version = min_firmware;
```

Postgres however has the `distinct on` operator which is usually faster than the corresponding solution with a window function:

```
select distinct on (test_type, model) 
       test_type, model, firmware_version, avg_throughput
from temp_table
order by test_type, model, firmware_version;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/563bd/1

Comment: I got super excited when I learned about "distinct on" here, and then found out Redshift doesn't seem to support it :(

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're looking for if I'm reading your post correctly, and I think it's a pretty easily readable way of doing it. :-)

```
WITH min_firmware_version (model, firmware_version)
AS
(
    SELECT
        model,
        MIN(firmware_version)
    FROM temp_table
    GROUP BY
        model
)
SELECT
    temp_table.model,
    temp_table.firmware_version,
    temp_table.avg_throughput
FROM temp_table
INNER JOIN min_firmware_version
    ON temp_table.model = min_firmware_version.model
    AND temp_table.firmware_version = min_firmware_version.firmware_version
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need that SQL statement:

```
SELECT t.test_type, t.model, t.firmware_version, t.avg_throughput 
FROM temp_table t 
WHERE t.firmware_version = (SELECT min(firmware_version) FROM temp_table)
```

Comment: You need a co-related subquery because otherwise you get the overal min(firmware_version) not the one for the model from the outer query

Comment: That's close but it selects the minimum version for all models but what if the minimum version is different for each model? Sorry the example table above is not very clear in this.