# How do I find a minimum value in a field and an associated value in an another field in a single query in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have a database of European countries. In the field on the very right, I have the population densities of all the listed countries. I have to find the smallest population density and display it and the country it belongs to in one query.

My best attempt:

```
SELECT Min(europa.Nepsuruseg) AS MinOfNepsuruseg, europa.Orszag
FROM europa
GROUP BY europa.Orszag;
```

This, however, displays all the countries and their population densities. How do I do this right?

[image: Example Data]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25271397/10815568 have you tried this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the TOP function to grab just the smallest one, after you sort by Nepsuruseg.

```
SELECT Top 1 europa.Nepsuruseg, europa.Orszag
FROM europa
Order By europa.Nepsuruseg ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to select the minimum population density across all records using a subquery.

Then in order to obtain all associated information held by the record or records whose population density field is equal to the minimum, you can either join the subquery to the main table, or include the subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Here is an example using an `INNER JOIN` on the subquery:

```sql
select t.* 
from europa t inner join
(
    select min(e.nepsuruseg) as mpd from europa e
) q
on t.nepsuruseg = q.mpd
```

Or, using the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
select t.* 
from europa t
where t.nepsuruseg = (select min(e.nepsuruseg) from europa e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is a bit too complex for my expertise, but I'm going to look into learning all this syntax.

Comment: @fajank0 If there are multiple records which share the same minimum population density, it depends on whether you would like to select one record, or all records which share the minimum.